# APIM 2.6.0 Micro Gateway - Class Cast Exception

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am getting class cast exception when trying to setup micro gateway in APIM 2.6.0. please advise.
please advise.
command executed : ./bin/micro-gw setup hello-world -a HelloWorld -v v1

```
[2021-01-06 15:19:21,126] DEBUG {org.wso2.apimgt.gateway.cli.rest.RESTAPIServiceImpl} - Retrieving API with name HelloWorld, version v1 was successful.                                      [2021-01-06 15:19:21,357] ERROR {org.wso2.apimgt.gateway.cli.cmd.Main} - Internal error occurred while executing command.java.lang.ClassCastException: org.wso2.apimgt.gateway.cli.model.rest.policy.BandwidthLimitDTO cannot be cast to org.wso2.apimgt.gateway.cli.model.rest.policy.RequestCountLimitDTO
    at org.wso2.apimgt.gateway.cli.model.template.policy.ThrottlePolicy.buildContext(ThrottlePolicy.java:138)
    at org.wso2.apimgt.gateway.cli.codegen.ThrottlePolicyGenerator.generateSubscriptionPolicies(ThrottlePolicyGenerator.java:97)
    at org.wso2.apimgt.gateway.cli.codegen.ThrottlePolicyGenerator.generate(ThrottlePolicyGenerator.java:59)
    at org.wso2.apimgt.gateway.cli.cmd.SetupCmd.execute(SetupCmd.java:298)
    at java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:159)
```

Comment: What is the microgateway version that you have used?

Comment: wso2am-micro-gw-2.6.0, - "4643". we are using Wso2 API Manager 2.6.0 so using same version of micro gateway.

Answer (score 0):

In this example, I had selected API that had Tier value selected as bandwidth based throttling. I have removed that and re-published this API to resolve issue. It worked after that. I do not need bandwidth based throttling right now, if someone need that then this issue will be there.Thanks